# Read only values from txt file

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, variables

i'm trying to read variables from a txt file.
The file .txt is like:

```
john 10
mark 230
peter 1
```

I would like to transfer and save this values in an array, for example array[0] = 10, array[1] = 230 etc without minding of names. I pasted my code below and I would like to know how can i edit it using this code below

```
int conf[4], i = 0, c;
FILE *file_conf;
file_conf = fopen("conf.txt", "r");

if(file_conf == NULL){
   fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else {
    while((c = fgetc(file_conf)) != EOF) { 
        fscanf(file_conf, "%d", &conf[i]);
        printf("%d\n", conf[i]);
        i++; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `fgetc()` at all--that gets a single character.  Instead, add the name format to your `fscanf()`, something like this:

```
char name[100];
fscanf(file_conf, "%s %d", name, &conf[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix `scanf()` family conversion specifiers with `*` to suppress assignment. Note that in the posted code, failure to check the value returned from `fscanf()` could lead to problems with malformed input. Also, the input loop should exit when the array index `i` grows too large to avoid buffer overflow. The following code exits the loop when `i` is too large, or when malformed input is encountered:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int conf[4], i = 0;
    FILE *file_conf;
    file_conf = fopen("conf.txt", "r");

    if(file_conf == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        while(i < 4 && fscanf(file_conf, "%*s%d", &conf[i]) == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", conf[i]);
            i++; 
        }
    }

    fclose(file_conf);

    return 0;
}
```

Output using using the posted sample input:

```
10
230
1
```